# Can't fadeOut element created with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, fadeout

I'm trying to get the rounded rectangle to fade out on click.. anyone know why it's not working?  If you go to the fiddle, click the "+" icon, enter in a hex code, then exit using the "x" in the top right, and try to click on the rounded rectangle with the color, it won't fade out.  The element is created with js obviously.

http://jsfiddle.net/DmYny/1/

This is the code that doesn't wanna work ::

```
$('.color').on('click', function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(300);
        });
```

Comment: use `$('body').on('click', '.color', function(){` instead of `$('.color').on('click', function(){` for live binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click handler is aplied to all those matching elements that exist at the time you run your jQuery function. If you create a new box with the `.color` class after that then it won't have the handler applied.

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click','.color', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(300);
    });
```

which will delegate the handler from the `body` element. It's not the best place to delegate from - you'd probably want to delegate from some container closer to the affected elements.

Comment: Thank you!  I thought it had something to do with the fact that the element was created after page load.  I'll use .module instead.